# Call to undefined method CI_Config::upload_url()

Tags: php, codeigniter

upload_url error
config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/*******/Admin-Panel/';
$config['root_upload_url']  = 'http://localhost/*******';
$config['upload_url']   = 'http://localhost/*******/uploads/';
$config['upload_dir_url']   = '/uploads/';
```

autoload

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

controller

```
$this->data['upload_url'] = upload_url();
```

Comment: where is your upload_url() show it ?

Comment: What is `upload_url()` over here?

Comment: upload url for upload the images. it is showing error in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if there's

```
$config['foo'] = 'bar';
```

in the config using

```
$this->config->item('foo');
```

This way you can get upload url path...